# TVirtualStringGrid CopyToClipboard issue Embarcadero Seattle C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Previously after calling `VirtualStringGrid -> CopyToClipBoard`, I could paste the grid as tabbed text in notepad or as a fully formatted grid (headers and colour and borders) when pasting into Excel or Outlook.

However, I'm experiencing issues with `CopyToClipboard` since I moved from Embarcadero XE8 to RAD Seattle with VirtualTreeView V6.2 : I only can paste as text if the target application is some kind of text editor. Pasting to any kind of 'rich' application that would accept RTF or html results in error.

I've tried to call the `ContentToXXX` methods (see code below) text is exported fine. Html is exported, but the resulting `Data2Export` string contains the whole code on an html page and cannot be pasted to Outlook, for instance.
Any call to `ContentToRTF` results in a crash.

I googled for this kind of issue but I did not find anything quite relevant.

```
void __fastcall TForm::ExportGrid( void )
{
// old code that used to work fine
//  VST->CopyToClipboard();

  Virtualtrees::TVSTTextSourceType exportSrcType = tstAll;

  OpenClipboard( Handle );
  EmptyClipboard();

  std::string Data2Export = "";
  HGLOBAL hg;

  // tabbed text
  Data2Export = AnsiString( VST->ContentToText( exportSrcType, "\t" ) ).c_str();
  hg = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.size() + 1 );

  if ( !hg )
  {
    CloseClipboard();
    return;
  }

  memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.size() + 1 );
  GlobalUnlock( hg );
  SetClipboardData( CF_TEXT, hg );
  GlobalFree( hg );

  // html
  Data2Export = AnsiString( VST->ContentToHTML( exportSrcType ) ).c_str();
  hg = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.size() + 1 );

  if ( !hg )
  {
    CloseClipboard();
    return;
  }

  memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.size() + 1 );
  GlobalUnlock( hg );
  SetClipboardData( CF_HTML, hg );
  GlobalFree( hg );

  // RTF
  Data2Export = AnsiString( VST->ContentToRTF( exportSrcType ).c_str() ).c_str();
  hg      = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.size() + 1 );

  if ( !hg )
  {
    CloseClipboard();
    return;
  }

  memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.size() + 1 );
  GlobalUnlock( hg );
  SetClipboardData( CF_TEXT, hg );
  GlobalFree( hg );

  CloseClipboard();
}
```

Any idea of how to solve or workaround this issue?

Something wrong with the code?

PD: the dev platform are Win8 and Win10 and the VirtualStringTree ClipboardFormats are all set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `GlobalFree()` after each call to `SetClipboardData()`.  YOU MUST NOT DO THAT unless `SetClipboardData()` fails.  The documentation is very clear on that matter:

[SetClipboardData function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051.aspx)

> If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter. **The application may not write to or free the data once ownership has been transferred to the system**, but it can lock and read from the data until the CloseClipboard function is called. (The memory must be unlocked before the Clipboard is closed.) If the hMem parameter identifies a memory object, the object must have been allocated using the function with the GMEM_MOVEABLE flag.

Also, you are saving your Text and RTF data blocks to the clipboard using the same `CF_TEXT` format.  Your RTF data should be using the `CF_RTF` format instead.

Try this:

```
#include <richedit.h>

void __fastcall TForm::ExportGrid( void )
{
    // old code that used to work fine
    //  VST->CopyToClipboard();

    Virtualtrees::TVSTTextSourceType exportSrcType = tstAll;

    if ( !OpenClipboard( Handle ) ) return;
    try
    {
        EmptyClipboard();

        AnsiString Data2Export;
        HGLOBAL hg;

        // tabbed text
        Data2Export = VST->ContentToText( exportSrcType, "\t" );
        hg = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.size() + 1 );
        if ( hg )
        {
            memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.Length() + 1 );
            GlobalUnlock( hg );
            if ( !SetClipboardData( CF_TEXT, hg ) ) // or maybe CF_CSV instead...
                GlobalFree( hg );
        }

        // html
        Data2Export = VST->ContentToHTML( exportSrcType );
        hg = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.Length() + 1 );
        if ( hg )
        {
            memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.Length() + 1 );
            GlobalUnlock( hg );

            if ( !SetClipboardData( CF_HTML, hg ) )
                GlobalFree( hg );
        }

        // RTF
        Data2Export = VST->ContentToRTF( exportSrcType );
        hg = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, Data2Export.Length() + 1 );
        if ( hg )
        {
            memcpy( GlobalLock( hg ), Data2Export.c_str(), Data2Export.Length() + 1 );
            GlobalUnlock( hg );

            if ( !SetClipboardData( CF_VRTF, hg ) )
                GlobalFree( hg );

        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

If you look at source code for VirtualTreeView's `CopyToClipboard()` method, it uses a very different implementation than the code above.  It retrieves the tree data into an `IDataObject` COM object (`TVTDataObject`) representing the clipboard formats listed in the VirtualTreeView's `ClipboardFormats` property, and any additional formats provided by the VirtualTreeView's `OnGetUserClipboardFormats` event. That includes Text, HTML, RTF, and CSV.  It then calls [`OleSetClipboard()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623.aspx) to put that COM object on the clipboard.  If any application uses `GetClipboardData()` instead of [`OleGetClipboard()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692778.aspx), Windows automatically extracts the data as needed. So maybe the implementation of `TVTDataObject` has been broken in v6.2.  You should contact [JAM Software](https://www.jam-software.de) (the current maintainers of VirtualTreeView) and file a bug report about that.

Comment: Hi Remy, I had missed the SetClipboardData trick. However the calling just `VST->ContentToRTF( TVSTTextSourceType::tstAll );` results in an access violation. I'll report the CopyToClipboard issue to Jam Software. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI here is the bug report and fix announced in version 6.2.1: [link](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/issues/588)